# SQL TOP results grouped by a field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've got a problem with an SQL query.  I have a list of 145 site names.  At each site certain species are found.  I've created a count of how many times each species have been seen at each site.  I want to find the 5 most common species seen at each site.  At present I have:

```
SELECT TOP 5 Count([bird point counts bound query].[Group size]) AS [CountOfGroup size], [bird point counts bound query].site, [bird point counts bound query].Species
FROM [bird point counts bound query]
GROUP BY [bird point counts bound query].site, [bird point counts bound query].Species
ORDER BY Count([bird point counts bound query].[Group size]) DESC;
```

this is only returning the 5 most commonly found species from all sites.  Just to clarify, with the top 5 results from each site and 145 sites, the resulting table should hold 725 records.  I'm working in Access at the moment.

any help appreciated as SQL is not my strong point.

Comment: "limit" instead of "top" perhaps

Comment: Oh, alas, the right way to solve this is with windows functions, and these are not support in Access.  Any change you can switch to a more functionality database, such as SQL Server?  Alternatively, you can do this in at the application level.

Comment: does ms-access sql have 'cross apply'?

Comment: Hi Gordon.  I can easily get this table into mySQL.  Not sure about sql Server though.  Never used it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can work out, you'll only get this done with a temp table in Access.

Something along these lines?

```
CREATE TABLE ##SiteSpecies (
  id            int IDENTITY (1,1),
  Site          <whatever>,
  Species       <whatever>,
  Observations  int
)

INSERT INTO ##SiteSpecies
SELECT   [bird point counts bound query].site, [bird point counts bound query].Species, Count([bird point counts bound query].[Group size])
FROM     [bird point counts bound query]
GROUP BY [bird point counts bound query].site, [bird point counts bound query].Species
ORDER BY [bird point counts bound query].site, [bird point counts bound query].Species, Count([bird point counts bound query].[Group size])

SELECT
  results.*
FROM
  ##SiteSpecies        AS results
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT Site, MIN(id) AS FirstID FROM ##SiteSpecies GROUP BY Site
)
  AS SiteMarkers
    ON  results.Site  = SiteMarkers.Site
    AND results.id   <= SiteMarkers.FirstID + 4
```

Comment: Were you able to get that to work in any version of MS Access?  When using suitable data types for the fields, `CREATE TABLE ##SiteSpecies` throws a syntax error with Access 2007.  The db engine will accept that name if bracketed ... [##SiteSpecies] ... but it doesn't really produce a temporary table.  The table is no more temporary than any other table created in the database.

Comment: For one thing, the INSERT statement should be "INSERT INTO ##SiteSpecies(Site, Species, Observations)".  As for the Access error, you can call the table anything, so long as you drop it when you are finished.